# How to check column contains values other than numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-like

I want to check if the column contains values other than numbers. I expect this query to print out the NULL values too, but it doesn't. I know the column contains NULL values. 
How can I change this query to get the NULL values as output too? Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT DISTINCT [1001account], [5028account], Balancesheettype
FROM [Cris_Ocean_tmp].[dbo].[NiiStressTest2018_v2_PUBLISHED_201812_CC_0326]
WHERE (StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0) AND (
    [1001account] NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' OR
    [5028account] NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
)
```

Comment: Please provide structure of the table and sample input/output data.

Answer (score 2):

`x NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'` will not match `ABC123` (which contains a value other than numbers). In SQL Server you could use could use `LIKE` with `[^...]`; and you need to check for NULLs separately:

```
WHERE column1 LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR column1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql ifnull statement:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/ifnull/

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
    [1001account], [5028account], Balancesheettype
    FROM 
    XXX
    WHERE
    (StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0)
    AND
    (
    IFNULL([1001account],0) NOT  LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    OR
    IFNULL([5028account],0) NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012+, you can use [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

To return records that aren't valid numbers (including `NULL`), do something like `WHERE TRY_PARSE(val AS INT) IS NULL`. Of course, performance will likely take a hit, but so will pretty much any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
where ISNULL(column,'1') LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```